# NoReverseMatch, reverse for login not found error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, http

I am trying to send an AJAX post request to a view but I am getting an Http500 error for some reason.

Here is the AJAX function:

```
function update_coins() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/coins",
    data: {"coins": transaction},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('yay')
      $( ".status" ).contents()[0].textContent = "Balance: " + data.coins
    }
  })
};
```

and I copy+pasted the necessary Django CSRF code above it.

The error I am getting is:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
"POST /coins HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

I'm guessing that this has something to do with my urls.py.

Here is my root app's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^coins$', views.update_coins, name='coins'),
    url(r'^shop', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

Here is my shop app's urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.shop, name='shop'),
]
```

and finally my users app's urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
        url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Thank you!

**EDIT 1: Added templates**
The base html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'assets/favicon.png' %}"/>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-social.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aladin" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block head-extras %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-white">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand">
          <h1 id="logo" class="nav-wel">Pomodoro</h1>
        </a>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <span class="status">Balance:&nbsp;{{ request.user.profile.coins }}<img class="coin-img" src="{% static 'assets/coin.png' %}" height="40px" width="auto"></span>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle welcome nav-wel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="welcome">Welcome {{ user.get_username }}</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/shop">Shop</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item">Leaderboard</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/change-password">Change Password</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/pomodoro.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The shop html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Pomodoro{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if request.GET.success %}
<div class="modal" id="logout-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-success main" role="alert">
          <p><b>You have successfully changed your password.</b></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
<audio id="coin-sound">
  <source src="{% static 'assets/coin.mp3' %}">
</audio>
<div class="row centre-v">
  <div class="card clock-card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <span class="motivation">Work hard, play hard.</span>
                <div class="clock-timer" id="clock-timer">
                    <span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg start-pomodoro">Start Pomodoro</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg start-break1 hidden">Start Break</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg start-break2 hidden">Start Break</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg reset hidden">Reset</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT 2: My views.py:**

```
@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def update_coins(request):
    """
    Function based view for increasing/decreasing a user's coin balance
    """
    try:
        user = request.user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No user matches the given query.")
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method=='POST':
        amount = request.POST.get("coins", 5)
        user.profile.coins += amount
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({'coins': user.profile.coins})
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: post the template where you have used something like {% url 'login' %}

Comment: I thought it would be a namespacing error based on what I have read but I don't use url tags anywhere. Posted though @Exprator

Comment: any template where you have used /login? seems this are not the templates

Comment: Nope, I've only used login as 'users/login' in an href tag or in my view as `@login_required(login_url='users/login')` @Exprator

Comment: remove that part or use @login_required(login_url='/users/login')

Comment: Still doesn't work @Exprator.

Comment: @login_required(login_url='/users/login/') try this

Comment: what did you do to get this error>? How is this related to Ajax? Did you add Ajax and you start getting this error?

Comment: I added the AJAX function in and then it started giving me the error. It comes when the POST request goes through @almostabeginner

Comment: Still doesn't work @Exprator.

Comment: add the coin function please and the decorators associated with it.

Comment: just keep @login_required() and remove the login_url once and check\

Comment: I thought I did, it's the first block of code @almostabeginner

Comment: Removed the entire decorator and it still gives the error @Exprator

Comment: url(r'^coins/$', views.update_coins, name='coins'),
and
 url: "/coins/", try this

Comment: Still getting the same error :(, thanks for the help though @Exprator

Comment: Do you have a `LOGIN_URL` setting in your `settings.py`? If not, try adding the following line: `LOGIN_URL = "users:login"`

Comment: Comment section is dragging lol. Can you access login page directly?

Comment: Use (login_url='users/login') instead of (login_url='/users/login') if it dixnt work try removing the caret ^ from beggining of login url

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your user app urls are overwriting the default login reverse view. Try renaming the login url name in `users app's urls.py` to something else and see if that works.